# Lotus Notes Domino changing computed field value when selecting on dialog list

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus-formula

I have a dialog list which contain "New Request" and "Edit Request", and a computed field which displays the list of available options when either "New Request" and "Edit Request" is selected. I can't seem to find a way to make it work, so what I did is that I made another computed field (so I have two field now), and hide field1 when "New Request" is not selected and field2 is hidden when "Edit Request" is not selected. But I think that is a lousy trick to make it work. Can you guys recommend me another way to do this? I'm new to lotus notes domino. By the way, here's my code to hide the fields:

```
RequestType != "New Request"
RequestType != "Edit Request"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the dialog list properties in second tab (Control tab) select the check box "Refresh fields on keyword change". Now in your computed field write your formula code something like this: `@If(RequestType = "New Request"; "Choice 1":"Choice 2":"Choice 3"; RequestType = "Edit Request"; "Choice 4":"Choice 5"; "Select a request type")`, which would return the three choices for new requests and the fourth and fifth choices for editing requests, while displaying instructional text if no choice has been made.